# View TSS in titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

Hi am new to titanium and cant get how to create a fluid design with its TSS. How to place three views, one as header(20%), two as content holder(60%) and three as footer(20%) with all width full(Ti.UI.FILL). My code is,

**index.xml**

```
<Alloy>
   <Window class="container">
       <Require src="home" id="home"></Require>
   </Window>
</Alloy>
```

**home.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <View id="header"></View>
    <View id="content"></View>
    <View id="footer"></View>
</Alloy>
```

**home.tss**

```
"#home": {
    layout: 'vertical',
    width: Ti.UI.FILL,
    height: Ti.UI.FILL,
    backgroundColor: '#000'
},
'#header':{
    layout: 'horizontal',
    height: '20%',
    width: Ti.UI.FILL,
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
},
'#content': {
    layout: 'vertical',
    height: '60%',
    width: Ti.UI.FILL,
    backgroundColor: '#ccc'
},
'#footer': {
    layout: 'horizontal',
    height: '20%',
    width: Ti.UI.FILL,
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
}
```

What am trying is to place a back button(left), title(middle) and a refresh button(right) as horizontal layout in **header view** and app content in **content view** and in **footer view** with some choice with scrolling(ie, we can scroll using slide event by placing options on it). If I run this code views are eventually divided as like [this](http://postimg.org/image/abfea4cjb/) and 60% not affected on the **content view**. I have asked in appcelerator forum and dint get replied yet. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your object with the id of 'home' isn't actually a view, it's just a reference to the home class and so you can't attribute styles to it like that.

I would have relaid home.xml out like this:

```
<Alloy>
    <View id="homeHolder">
        <View id="header"></View>
        <View id="content"></View>
        <View id="footer"></View>
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

and then this would have work as you would have expected

```
"#homeHolder": {
    layout: 'vertical',
    width: Ti.UI.FILL,
    height: Ti.UI.FILL,
    backgroundColor: '#000'
}
```

Comment: Great it works like charm. Thank you Martyn. I dont know how to put code in comments. I will put it as next answer that others can take.

Answer (score 1):

Put this:

```
"#home": {
    layout: 'vertical',
    width: Ti.UI.FILL,
    height: Ti.UI.FILL,
    backgroundColor: '#000'
},
```

Inside `index.tss`, there is no element with id `home` inside *home.xml*, but there is one inside *index.xml*.

Comment: Thanks Josiah Hester --> If we provide **top: 0** in #header and **bottom: 0** in #footer its working correctly.

Comment: Yes, that is one way to do it, but if you don't fix what I pointed out, it will cause you trouble and confusion later on! Doing what you did also means you will lose a lot, since your `layout: vertical` is unused.

Comment: Thanks Josiah. For index.xml, we did not have **id as index** in xml(view) but if we call **$.index it calls index view**. Hence I put **id=home** in **index view** and it will call **home view**. Is it right??

Answer (score 1):

**home.xml**

```
<Alloy>
<View id="home">
    <View id="header" visible="true">
        <Label>header</Label>
    </View>
    <ScrollView id="content" visible="true">
        <Label>content</Label>
    </ScrollView>
    <View id="footer" visible="true">
        <Label>footer</Label>
    </View>
</View>
</Alloy>
```

**home.tss**

```
"#home": {
layout: 'vertical',
width: Ti.UI.FILL,
height: Ti.UI.FILL,
backgroundColor: '#000'
},
'#header':{
    layout: 'horizontal',
    height: '20%',
    width: Ti.UI.FILL,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
},
'#content': {
    layout: 'vertical',
    height: '60%',
    width: Ti.UI.FILL,
    backgroundColor: '#ccc'
},    
'#footer': {
    layout: 'horizontal',
    height: '20%',
    width: Ti.UI.FILL,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
}
```

**index.xml**

```
<Alloy>
<Window class="container">
    <Require src="home" id="home"></Require>
</Window>
</Alloy>
```

This works. Thanks to Martyn.